# Vlookup / Match max min number on different worksheet

Tags: excel, match, vlookup

I have 2 worksheets, one with company data and the other with a min max and answer column.

What i need to do is find out if value in column D in the company data is between the min/max in worksheet 2 output answer in worksheet 2.

Please can someone help.  This is clearly a vlookup question but i haven't got a clue how to do the min/max.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

worksheet 1

```
NAME                    TYPE    NUMBEROFEMPLOYEES   Output
Wetland Plants Ltd      Client  4   
Capital Management LLP  Clients 3   
College ltd             Clients 156
```

Worksheet 2

```
max         min     output
100000000   60000   big
59999       15000   medium
14999       0       small
```

Cheers guys

Comment: The worksheets haven't turned out as i had hoped on here.

Comment: which column do they have in common?

Comment: Number of employees, but on table 2 these have min and max values.  I have rearranged table 2 to display with smallest min max values at the top going down.

Barry Houdini's answer only puts out the highest number all of the time.  Any ideas Barry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As TheGreatCO says, you need to re-arrange the table to make VLOOKUP (or LOOKUP) work but if you want the tables to remain as they are then try this formula in sheet1 E2

`=INDEX(Sheet2!C$2:C$4,MATCH(D2,Sheet2!A$2:A$4,-1))`

Assumes that D2 contains the number of employees and that your sheet2 table is in A2:C4 (Max in A2:A4, Min in B2:B4 and output in C2:C4)

You can copy the formula down the column....

Comment: Number of employees, but on table 2 these have min and max values. I have rearranged table 2 to display with smallest min max values at the top going down. Barry Houdini's answer only puts out the highest number all of the time. Any ideas Barry?

Comment: My formula was based on you having the tables as you showed in the question, if you re-arrange to have the smallest values first then you can use LOOKUP like `=LOOKUP(D2,sheet2!B$2:B$4,sheet2!C$2:C$4)` where MIN values are in sheet2!B2:B4

Answer (score 0):

You can do a VLOOKUP only if the key data column (column with data you are looking up by) is in ascending alphanumeric order, eg. from 0 to 9, a to z.  In this case, your worksheet 2 should be (from top to bottom) 14999 -> 0, 59999 -> 15000, 100000000 -> 60000.

Comment: for excel versions 2007+ you dont need to sort for vlookup

Comment: VLOOKUP doesn't require sorting in `ANY` version......if you are searching for an `exact match` (with FALSE as 4th argument) but here sorting is required because the match isn't necessarily exact, e.g. 156 needs to match with 0 in MIN column to return "Small" - if min values are sorted ascending you can use VLOOKUP with TRUE or 1 as 4th argument (or you can use LOOKUP as per my comment in my answer)